# bashrc and export variables

Tags: bash, variables, export

I am adding a variable that I want to be exported every time I run a terminal window. The problem is that it points to a file or directory that is not made at this time. But I want the bash to load and export the variable anyways because when I use it the file/folder will be there.

the variables

```
export ports=$(awk -F "/" 'BEGIN {ORS=","} /\/tcp/ {print $1}' nmap/initial.nmap | sed 's/,$//')
export portsf=$(awk -F "/" 'BEGIN {ORS=","} /\/tcp/ {print $1}' nmap/full.nmap | sed 's/,$//')
```

error messages:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `nmap/initial.nmap' for reading (No such file or directory)
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `nmap/full.nmap' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

Is there any way to make this work through the bashrc or am I going to have make an alias that will export the variable I want each terminal session?

thanks for your time.

Comment: The command substitution runs immediately; it's not deferred until you actually want the value of `ports`. You'll have to wait until `nmap/*.nmap` exist to define the variables.

Comment: oh okay thanks!, i will have to set my exports to aliases and use them that way after I create the nmap/*.nmap.

edit: alias --> echo "export string so at the very least copy and paste" thanks!

Comment: I would recommend functions rather than aliases.

Comment: How would I do name function in the bashrc?

Comment: How would I do name function in the bashrc?

would it be something like this?
function ports() {
      export ports....
}
export -f ports

Comment: You don't export the function. You just call the function once the input is available. Any variables you set in the body of the function are global by default. You don't need to export the variables, either. It appears you'll be using them as ordinary shell variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also check for existence of the files in your .bashrc and execute the exports command only if they exist.
Something like this should work:

```
[ -f nmap/initial.nmap ] && export ports=$(awk -F "/" 'BEGIN {ORS=","} /\/tcp/ {print $1}' nmap/initial.nmap | sed 's/,$//')
[ -f nmap/full.nmap ] && export portsf=$(awk -F "/" 'BEGIN {ORS=","} /\/tcp/ {print $1}' nmap/full.nmap | sed 's/,$//')
```

what is after '&&' will be evaluated only if what is before '&&' exits with exit code 0. Concretely here for the first line for example, if the file 'nmap/initial.nmap' exists, you will indeed export the 'ports' variable and not otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following function to your `.bashrc`.

```
set_ports () {
    awk 'F "/" 'BEGIN {ORS=","} /\/tcp/ {print $1}' "$1" | sed 's/,$//'
}
```

Once the required files are availble, you can run

```
ports=$(set_ports nmap/initial.nmap)
portsf=$(set_ports nmap/full.nmap)
export ports ports
```

You can omit the last line if you don't actually need to export the variables (which I suspect is the case).

Comment: thats what i have